# Cant connect to bluetooth headphones. "Failed to connect"

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

When i try to connect to my bluetooth headphones i get the error, "Device added successfully, but failed to connect"

Why? I've done this on previous versions of ubuntu and it has worked.
[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcP31.png)

Comment: I have the same problem with my wife's notebook (Ubuntu 15.10). It simply can't connect to JBL speakers she had bought ... grgrgr.
Any idea?

Comment: Yes, i recently fixed it. Change the audio profile